# setState function comes up as undefined when passed to helper

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to take a picture, and when that picture returns its prediction in the backend update the state. However, I cannot get the function to pass in, it only comes up as undefined. I know redux would probably be the best solution for this, but this is the only piece of state in the whole app where I have an issue, so I would rather avoid it if possible.

Here is my file:

```
const CameraRender = (props) => {
  const [predictionLoaded, isPredictionLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [showModal, changeModalVisability] = useState(false);
  const [proportions, setProportions] = useState([]);
  const { setCameraInactive } = props;

  return(
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Camera
        style={styles.container}
        ref={ref => {
          this.camera = ref;
        }}
      >
        <View style={styles.rectangle} />
        <View style={styles.pictureButton}>
          <Ionicons
            name='ios-camera'
            size={60}
            color={'#cdd2c9'}
            onPress={() => pictureHandler(this.camera, isPredictionLoaded(true),
                                          changeModalVisability(true), ((p1, p2) =>
                                          setProportions([p1, p2])))}
          />
        </View>
      </Camera>
      {showModal &&
        <PostPicModal
          predictionLoaded
          proportions
          setCameraInactive={() => setCameraInactive()}
          changeModalVisability={() => changeModalVisability(false)}
        />
      }
    </View>
  );
}

const pictureHandler = async (camera, addPic, isPredictionLoaded,
                              changeModalVisability, setProportions) => {
  const photo = await this.camera.takePictureAsync({ onPictureSaved: this.camera.pausePreview()});
  changeModalVisability();
  const prediction = await requestPrediction(photo.uri);
  setProportions(prediction[0][0], prediction[0][1]); //THIS ISNT WORKING
  isPredictionLoaded();
}
```

I know this is easy enough when I am passing it to another functional component, but I really just wanted to have a helper function that could take in the state. Should I just move picture handler right into the onPress? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with argument passing.

You are passing 4 arguments, however in your function you have expected 5 arguments.

I believe `addPic` is missing argument when you are calling a function.

I can see issue in passing arguments as well, it should be just `isPredictionLoaded` and inside the function you can call it with true or false like `isPredictionLoaded(true)`